# How is r calculated in Kest (spatstat)?

Tags: r, spatial

I cannot seem to find how the search distance "r" is calculated in the R Kest function (spatstat).  The package [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/Kest) states the following:

> r Optional. Vector of values for the argument r at which K(r) should
>   be evaluated. Users are advised not to specify this argument; there is
>   a sensible default.

What is the "sensible default" used in the calculation?  Any documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `R` is open source you can read the code yourself. Typing `Kest` lists the code. Finding where `r` is assigned shows it is done by a subroutine called `handle.r.b.args`. Type its name at the `R` prompt to read the procedure--it's only a half dozen lines:

```
    rmax <- if (missing(rmaxdefault)) 
        diameter(as.rectangle(window))
    else rmaxdefault
    if (is.null(eps)) {
        if (!is.null(window$xstep)) 
            eps <- window$xstep/4
        else eps <- rmax/512
    }
    breaks <- make.even.breaks(rmax, bstep = eps)
```

Evidently an estimate of the diameter of the region is divided by 512.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on the very helpful answer by @whuber, I was able to find additional details on the exact calculations used for r in Kest:

> *How are the r values determined in Kest(X) ?*
>
> The default r values for Kest are computed as follows:
>
> The maximum r value is computed by the function 'rmax.rule', rmax <-
> rmax.rule("K", W, lambda) where W is the window containing the data,
> and lambda is the average density of points per unit area. Currently
> this rule takes the minimum of Ripley's rule of thumb: rmax = one
> quarter of the smallest side of the enclosing rectangle large sample
> rule: rmax = sqrt(1000/(pi * lambda)) r values are equally spaced from
> 0 to rmax with step value 'eps'. If eps is not specified, then eps =
> rmax/512 so that there are 513 values or 512 intervals. You can always
> override the 'r' values if you need to.

Source: [spatstat](http://www.spatstat.org/spatstat/spatstatFAQ.html)